# Wordpress media uploading with round robin load balancing

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, apache

I have a server a dedicated server "srv1" , which has a website hosted, that has a lot of traffic, So we decided to set up load balancing , so the website files are now present on 2 servers "srv1" and "srv2" , Its a WordPress Install so my database is present on "srv1" , All is working fine, except for when it comes to media uploading. media gets uploaded on either one of the 2 servers. and is missing on the other server. Is there any easy way to overcome this, or writing a cron to check the uploads folder and synchronizing the two is the only solution? a common domain points to both the servers using round robin.